# How to create unique id entries and filter for specific column values for these ids (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, distinct-values

Below you can see for each customer several product entries and the time they bought the product. However I am only intersted whether they ever bought product 1, and if they have never bought it I would fill the cell with product x instead of skipping the id. I am using Postgresql!

This is the current table:

[image: product]

and this is the desired outcome:

[image: product2]

I am trying this table but it does not provide quite what I am looking for. Is it possible to transform the first table into the 2nd at all?

```
select distinct on ("id")
"id", "buying date", "product",
case when "product"='product 1' then 'product 1' else 'product x' as "Product2"
from product
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the logic you want should be in the `order by` clause:

```
select distinct on ("id")
       "id", "buying date", "product"
from product
order by id,
         ("product" = 'product 1') desc,  -- put product1 first
         "buying date";
```

For a boolean expression, `DESC` orders the `true` value first then the `false`.

Comment: why do you choose desc? doesn't it mean that for any id that is for example mentioned 3 times, ("product" = 'product 1') wil appear 3rd?

Comment: @sweti: DESC because you want the TRUE output first: ("product" = 'product 1') desc